# Effect of temperature and pressure on structure of solids

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, pressure

What is the effect of these conditions on the structure of solids? My book has the answer that confuses me. I got nothing about it. Can you please explain? The answer of the book is

> With the increase in temperature, coordination number of ion decrease. With the increase in pressure the coordination number of ions increase.

Comment: Roughly speaking, that is generally correct. Increasing temperature, which implies increasing atomic vibrations, might make a less dense, more open crystal structure the preferred option. Increasing pressure will favor small volume crystal structures, increasing the number of nearest neighbors.